# retrieving the primary_connection_string from azure signalr using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, signalr-hub

One of the things we are not able to solve is how to retrieve the primary connection string from the azure signal r service (which is commissioned through terraform) and we can perfectly access it in the portal.

We expect to be able to access the primary connection string with the following command

```
output "signalr_primary_connection_string" {
value = "${azurerm_signalr_service.projectx.primary_connection_string}"
}
```

The resource was created as

```
resource "azurerm_signalr_service" "projectx" {
  name                = "xx-projectx-signalr"
  location            = "${var.region}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.OnePoc.name }"
  sku {
    name     = "Standard_S1"
    capacity = 1
  }
}
```

It looks from the documentation that we should be able to retrieve this 
and I need it to wire it to a function otherwise we are not having automation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it like you try to ([proof](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/signalr_service.html#primary_connection_string)). You just need to update to the latest azure provider (1.22) version. This capability was released 4 days ago.

Comment: Nice, the version changed between I started using terraform and now :-)
Completly missed that.
Thanks for the quick answer.